# How to remove class attribute from div?

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript and I want to add/remove a Class attribute if a button is clicked. I am able to add the class, but I don't know how to remove it. how can I do that?

```
window.onload = function(){
    var buttonGo = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    var buttonCom = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1];
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    buttonGo.onclick = function(){
        box.setAttribute('class','move');
    }
    buttonCom.onclick = function(){
        // how to remove class name?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`box.removeAttribute("class")` should work.

Answer (score 8):

The nicest way to set classes with Javascript is to use the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className) property:

```
// to add
box.className = 'move';
// to remove
box.className = '';
```

Comment: It seems that doing this leaves `<div class>` in the DOM (at least in today's stable Chrome's devtools DOM view). Calling `removeAttribute` does completely remove the attribute. Presumably this can make a difference to resource usage if done on a significant scale.

Answer (score 7):

```
function hasClass(ele,cls) {
    return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}
function addClass(ele,cls) {
    if (!this.hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
}
function removeClass(ele,cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
        ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
    }
}
```

You can use RegExp in theses three functions to check class existance, add class, and remove class.  Here is the source [openjs](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/dom/class_manipulation.php)

Comment: If you're going to copy and paste code, please credit your source.

Answer (score 6):

Simple:

```
box.removeAttribute('class');
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeAttribute

Answer (score 4):

In the future-ish, you can also consider [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```
   var d = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
   d.classList; // []
   d.classList.add('foo'); // undefined
   d.classList; // ["foo"]
   d.classList.remove('foo'); // undefined
   d.classList; // []
```

I say future-ish b/c you have to consider this IE < 10.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
window.onload = function(){
            var buttonGo = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
            var buttonCom = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1];
            var box = document.getElementById('box');
            buttonGo.onclick = function(){
                box.setAttribute('class','move');
            }
            buttonCom.onclick = function(){
               box.className=''
            }
       }
```

or double quotes  `box.className=""`

Comment: i know this, but i don't lke. all time we can't use it.

Comment: @3gwebtrain well you didn't mention in your question that you don't like this or tried/but not like it. I just offered a solution .. its up to you which one to accept

Answer (score 1):

For cross-browser support:

```
buttonCom.onclick = function() {
    box.className = ''; // IE
    box.removeAttribute('class'); // Others
};
```

Answer (score -4):

You should consider jQuery, than you can just use this: `$('.itemclass').removeClass('classname');`

Comment: jQuery answers to vanilla JavaScript questions are not encouraged.